# SNS no envía push notifications a endpoint ios

Tags: ios, aws

Hola estoy tratando de enviar Push notifications a través del servicio sns de aws, con la configuración APNs para dispositivos ios, y no puedo realizar un envío éxitos y  creo que tengo los certificados bien configurados. Ahora lo que veo raro es que  cuando envío un push notification por primera vez me dice envío exitoso pero el Platform application que cree se pone en estado deshabilidado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En dónde configuras el `Bundle identifier`? Debería estar con el de tu aplicación de Xcode.

Comment: Hola perdon mi desconocimiento, lo unico que me pide en la configuracion del plataform application es el .p12, y para el endpoint le paso el token id

Comment: Puedes usar este programa [Pusher](https://pusher.com/tutorials/push-notifications-ios/) para simular notificaciones push, necesitas los certificados. Si funciona entonces debes revisar lo del `Bundle identifier` de tu app.

Comment: Revisa también los roles que estás asginando ... el rol del servicio debe permitir el uso de SNS